# Splitting polylines / multipart lines at intersections using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, splitting

I have a network which is a multipart line (that was originally created from polylines which were not split at desired location). See image.

[image]

How do I convert this network such that it is split only at intersections? See image.

[image]

Comment: Use feature to line tool in ArcGIS: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50232/splitting-roads-at-intersection-for-arcgis-network-analyst